# What does it mean for two random variables to have a jointly continuous PDF?

Tags: continuity, random-variables

Two random variables X,Y can have a joint PDF $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ that is continuous but $X,Y$ themselves are not continuous. The example I saw in class was if $X$ is a continuous random variable and $Y=X$, then the set $\{(X,Y) \in \mathbb(R)^2 | x=y\}$ "has zero area but unit probability, which is impossible for jointly continuous random variables."

(1) I can't entirely grasp this example -- why is this not a valid joint continuous PDF (it is a continuous function, what else do we need)?

(2) More importantly, what does it even mean for a PDF to be jointly continuous (from both a functional and probabilistic perspective)? It implies that the components are individually continuous, but somehow the converse is not a necessary and sufficient condition, and I can't see why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think an analogy is the easiest way to demonstrate that $(X,Y)$ is not jointly-continuous. Consider a random variable $U$ which has a uniform distribution on $[0, \delta]$. $U$ is a continuous random variable and has a pdf, $f_U(u) = 1/\delta$ provided that $\delta>0$. But as soon as you set $\delta=0$, $U$ becomes a "degenerate" random variable which has a discrete distribution defined by $P(U=u) = 1$ if $u=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now consider a bivariate extension of this. Let $X$ be any continuous r.v. and let $Y = X + U$, where again $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, \delta]$. It can easily be shown that the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x) /\delta$. If $X:=Y$, then that corresponds to the situation where $\delta = 0$. But that would mean that the joint pdf is infinite at every point which violates the definition of pdf's. Thus, we are instead left with a "mixed-distribution" where one variable is continuous and the other is discrete.